# webpack replace only one file in library (bootstrap)

Tags: webpack

In project used angular 2 + webpack + bootstrap

I want use custom theme for bootstrap - replace **node_modules/../bootstrap.css** with **./Content/bootstrap.min.css**

I add alias for that

```json
alias: {
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css': './Content/bootstrap.min.css',
        }
```

but have errors

> ```
> Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' in '\Content'
>  @ ./Content/bootstrap.min.css
> ```

How I can replace a file but not change the folder for depend resources

example

*glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot* must be searched in *\node_modules* not in *Content*

Comment: why not modify `/Content/bootstrap.min.css` and fix the reference over there?

Comment: Can you post complete webpack config?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe another alias that says:

```
'./Content/fonts': 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts'
```

Seems a bit hacky, but maybe give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CopyWebpackPlugin to load css,js file.Try this code

**npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev**

```
  resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {
            Content$: path.resolve(__dirname, './Content'),         
        }
    },

plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', to: './Content' }
        ])
]
```